# Merge two Batch Files into one

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i have written a small script that is taking infos from an console application and sending it via email to me. I have used Quiet to let the programm run in the background.

start.bat

```
Quiet script.bat
```

script.bat

```
info.exe > "data.txt"
sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a "data.txt" 
del "data.txt"
```

if i run it like this it works fine but when i try to make one file of it like:

script.bat

```
Quiet script.bat
info.exe > "data.txt"
sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a      data.txt" 
del "data.txt"
```

It sends infinte amount of emails. When i make it like this it works but not like i want it to.

script.bat

```
Quiet script.bat
pause
info.exe > "data.txt"
sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a      data.txt" 
pause
del "data.txt"
```

Comment: Are you launching this by clicking the start batch file?

Comment: Yeah but i want it to be just one Batch file and not two.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the infinite mails is that you call the batch file inside the batch file, which causes an infinite loop of running the batch.

The problem is with the logic of what that you are expecting to happen,
you want to click the batch file and expect that it will run by Quiet before it runs in shell.

If you just want to run it in background, you can easily achieve it by running it as "System"(with a service/schedule task and etc.), otherwise I think that you can't resolve this issue(you expect that another executable will run the current batch you are clicking - the first batch will always open a window).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Not sure I understood everything.

One way would be in *script.bat*

Probably echo are needed in front of each command. if it doesn't work, try in one line

```
@echo off
( 
echo info.exe > "data.txt"
echo sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a "data.txt" 
echo del "data.txt"
) > output.txt 2>&1 | Quiet.exe
```

Or in one liner

```
@echo off
( 
echo info.exe > "data.txt" &&^
echo sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a "data.txt" &&^ 
echo del "data.txt" &&^
) > output.txt 2>&1 | Quiet.exe
```

In this way, start.bat is not necessary.
Which is equivalent to this:

```
Quiet.exe info.exe > "data.txt" && sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a "data.txt" && del "data.txt"
```

**EDIT:**

```
@echo off
Quiet start cmd /c "info.exe > 'data.txt' && sendEmail -o tls=yes -f myemail@gmail.com -t myemail@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypasswd -u "XXX" -m "XXX" -a 'data.txt' && del 'data.txt'"
Pause
```

In the last example, you have to deal with double quotes, probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are clicking to start the program, the shortcut can have the launching command in it, changed in the properties.

```
"c:\folder\Quiet.exe" "c:\batch\folder\script.bat"
```

and then there is just the one batch file.